# Dividers between Parent cells and not child cells of ExpandableListView

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview, spacing

There are several questions addressing this, but none have answers that work for me. I am trying to add about a 10 dp space between parent cells of an ExpandableListView, but not between child cells. I have tried almost everything. The catch is that I need the parent cells to also be rounded when not expanded, and then half-rounded (only top corners) when expanded. The final child in each group is then half rounded (the opposite way) when expanded, so each group is like a rounded square as a whole. I've already accomplished the rounding of corners, but can't get space between parent cells.

Could somebody please give me a good way to do this?

My current attempt:

```
@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return (bunches.size()*2)-1;
}
```

... in getGroupView() I set view based on position ...

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        if (groupPosition%2!=0) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fakeview, null);
        } else {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.header_item, null);
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_listview_item_header_expanded);
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expandable_list_title);
            holder.numberOfMembers = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.num_members_textview);
            holder.editImageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.header_item_imageview_edit);
        }
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    if (isExpanded) {
        convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_listview_item_expanded);

    } else {
        convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_listview_item);
    }
...
```

But this throws a null pointer when creating the cells:

```
11-21 10:00:39.542: E/AndroidRuntime(28855): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-21 10:00:39.542: E/AndroidRuntime(28855): Process: me.lunchbunch.stage, PID: 28855
11-21 10:00:39.542: E/AndroidRuntime(28855): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
11-21 10:00:39.542: E/AndroidRuntime(28855):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:715)
11-21 10:00:39.542: E/AndroidRuntime(28855):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
11-21 10:00:39.542: E/AndroidRuntime(28855):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
11-21 10:00:39.542: E/AndroidRuntime(28855):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
11-21 10:00:39.542: E/AndroidRuntime(28855):    at me.lunchbunch.core.listadapter.BunchesActivityListAdapter.getGroupView(BunchesActivityListAdapter.java:125)
11-21 10:00:39.542: E/AndroidRuntime(28855):    at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:446)
11-21 10:00:39.542: E/AndroidRuntime(28855):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
11-21 10:00:39.542: E/AndroidRuntime(28855):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
11-21 10:00:39.542: E/AndroidRuntime(28855):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
11-21 10:00:39.542: E/AndroidRuntime(28855):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:759)
11-21 10:00:39.542: E/AndroidRuntime(28855):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1673)
11-21 10:00:39.542: E/AndroidRuntime(28855):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2151)
11-21 10:00:39.542: E/AndroidRuntime(28855):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
11-21 10:00:39.542: E/AndroidRuntime(28855):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
11-21 10:00:39.542: E/AndroidRuntime(28855):    at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:581)
11-21 10:00:39.542: E/AndroidRuntime(28855):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
11-21 10:00:39.542: E/AndroidRuntime(28855):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
11-21 10:00:39.542: E/AndroidRuntime(28855):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
```

My guess is that it is throwing an error because it looks for the attributes of the holder on an empty holder (the dividers)

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception ? Can you post the whole view creation code ?

Comment: post the log trace for exception

Comment: isnt it possible like android:dividerHeight="Your desired height";?

Comment: I've added all getGroupView (except for variable setting for ViewHolder) and the logs

Answer (score 0):

NullPointerException in

```
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:715)
```

probably means the view holder is not initialized correctly

You are setting the holder inside the else. I am guessing what you need it to be is like this?

```
if (groupPosition%2!=0) {
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fakeview, null);
} else {
   convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.header_item, null);
   convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_listview_item_header_expanded);  
}
holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expandable_list_title);
holder.numberOfMembers = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.num_members_textview);
holder.editImageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.header_item_imageview_edit);
```